# mvc:annotation-driven is not bound

Tags: spring

I get this error when I run a certain Spring Web 3 project in NetBeans:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 30; The
>   prefix "mvc" for element
>   "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound.

Here's `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.myproject.controllers"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

I think I did the appropriate namespace declarations, but obviously I'm still overlooking something. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should work like that, and it works for me. The problem might be in your IDE / xml editor. Try ignoring the xml error and run the application.

Comment: The application doesn't crash or anything, but experience has taught me to never ever ignore warnings. So you're saying it might be a NetBeans or Ant bug?

Comment: yes. Most likely. I just saved your dispatcher-servlet in eclipse and it is saved without problems.

Answer (score 40):

This is an IDE Error, Which can be resolved by following to

> xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

[image]

Comment: Simply superb.. It worked like a charm for my code. Thank you so very much for the help.

Comment: for me, i had to first remove this line and then add it again, to work

Comment: Still helpful, even 4 years later.. ;-) Issue on InteliJ IDEA

Comment: Well, it is 2020 now and perfectly clear that "not bound" really means there was no valid name space provided to resolve what <mvc:annotation-driven /> is supposed to do. Once I added the mvc xml name space as described above everything was resolved.

Answer (score 27):

try this it worked for me:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an IDE Error, Which can be resolved by adding the following to your Spring Dispatcher Servlet

xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

And also add the following snippet if it is not included in your xml file

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"

Answer (score 2):

Changing below code worked for me

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

to below code (imp : check xmlns:context and xmlns:xsi position)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing some significant portion of the namespace declaration, as discussed here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?100397-The-prefix-mvc-for-element-mvc-annotation-driven-is-notbound

It does not effect runtime, but the development environment will suffer with similar problems as you describe.

I guess it should go this way:
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd

Comment: can you elaborate your answer? not describing solution to problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add:
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

Otherwise xml will not understand the p annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
so I added : http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
to xsi:schemaLocation
here is my bean tag :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring- 
       context.xsd">
```

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly was the solution you applied?

Comment: @Yunnosch , in the file spring-servlet.xml I added to xsi:shemaLocation inside the bean tag that link.