# Simple REST service using Spring MVC, problems with configuration

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to add a simple REST service to a default Spring MVC Template project created using the SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) and Eclipse. The REST service I want to expose is basically a utility that's not tied to any model. The input is a string and I want it to return the string reversed. The code part is easy, but the configuration is not. Below are my relevant files.

I don't really understand why this doesn't work, but when I type in the URL http://localhost:8080/projectName/restfultest/stringreverser/testString I get the error message 
    No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/projectName/restfultest/stringreverser/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'restfulServlet'

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>restfulServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/restfulServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>restfulServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restfultest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.pkg" />



</beans:beans>
```

RestfulService.java

```
package com.sample.pkg;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/stringreverser")
public class RestfulService {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String reverseId(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        String reversed = "";
        for (int i = id.length() - 1; i <= 0; --i) {
            reversed += id.charAt(i);
        }

        return reversed;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

-Joe

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:8080/restfultest/stringreverser/testString` ?

Comment: just try without the "projectName" part in your URL.

Comment: Tried that, but the server gave me a 404 error without any details from the console. It's the same error I would get if I tried http://localhost:8080/foo/bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First off, you reversal function is incorrect

```
for (int i = id.length() - 1; i <= 0; --i) {...}
```

It will never go in, as you expect `i` to be less than or equal to `0` on start.

#### Second of all, here's some good news

[image]

#### Here is a working controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( value="/stringreverser" )
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping( value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET )
    public String reverseId( @PathVariable String id, Model model ) {

        StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder();
        for ( int i = id.length() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            reversed.append( id.charAt( i ) );
        }

        logger.debug( "\n\t [" + id + "] reversed ==> " + reversed.toString() );

        model.addAttribute( "originalId", id );
        model.addAttribute( "reversedId", reversed.toString() );

        return "home";
    }
}
```

Controller name is `HomeController`, since I used a templated Spring MVC app that you can create in two clicks with [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts):

- `File` => `New` => `Spring Template Project`
- Choose "Spring MVC Project", enter project name, top level package ( e.g. org.guru.xyz ), click `Next`
- You have yourself a brand new "Spring MVC" project
- In order to deploy it, right click on your project ( on the left hand side ), go to "Run As" => "Run On Server"
- This will deploy it to Tomcat and open a "localhost:8080/somemvc/" where you would see "Hello world!"

But the way, it'll already have a, missing from your code above, view resolver and a `home.jsp`, that you see rendered on the picture above.

#### Here is the `home.jsp`

```
<html>
  <head> <title>Mean ID Reverser</title> </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Mean ID Reverser </h1>
    <p>  I just reversed your ID "${originalId}" => "${reversedId}" </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### And

`<url-pattern>/restfultest/*</url-pattern>` in `web.xml` works just fine.

---

### JSON Woodoo

In order to return it as JJ (Just JSON), there are just two things you need to do:

#### Add a Jackson Mapper dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Change a return type to `@ResponseBody Object`

```
@RequestMapping( value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET )
public @ResponseBody Object reverseIdJson(@PathVariable String id) {        
    return new ReverserResult( id );
}
```

I included an object `ReversalResult` instead of a simple String in order to demonstrate a transparent Jackson Mapper magic, and to see that it is truly a JSON response that comes back:

[image]

where a `ReversalResult` has two fields, a `reverseString` static method, and it reverses a String in a constructor:

```
    private String original;
    private String reversed;

    public ReverserResult( String reverseMe ) {
        this.original = reverseMe;
        this.reversed = reverseString( reverseMe );
    }
```

This of course would just be a stand alone function, but again, I wanted to show the Object with 1+ fields to come back as JSON.

Comment: I saw the view resolver section that was in there for the sample application, but I wasn't sure if it was necessary in my situation. I don't have a stringreverser.jsp page inside of the WEB-INF directory, but I want the reverseId() function to be called on whatever string is provided by the URL. Do I need a viewResolver anyway? Also, I tried adding the mvc: part to annotation-driven but eclipse complained about 'The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound." It didn't complain without the mvc part so I assumed it was able to find that configuration option.

Comment: in order to get `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to work, you have to add XML schema (`xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` and friends), see this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001593/mvcannotation-driven-is-not-bound) on the simple config. Yes, I would leave a view resolver there.

Comment: I do not think that the missing namespace is an issue, as he has defined mvc namespace to be his default namespace.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild, good catch, I see that. Then I have another little thing to try ( besides the view resolver => keep it there ) => Remove the `*` in `<url-pattern>/restfultest/*</url-pattern>`.

Comment: Okay, so I left the viewResolver in there. Taking the * out of the url-pattern seems to have the effect of only matching projectName/restfultest/, giving me the same warning output as before (No mapping found for HTTP request ...). Anything else gives me a 404 page with no warning printed out. It would seem to me like the regex is working fine with the *, but something is missing from the configuration.

Comment: remove the class level `@RequestMapping`, I edited the answer.

Comment: @tolitius you are a gentleman and a scholar. I believe my biggest issue was that my reverseId method wasn't taking in a model as the second argument. If I modified the resolver could I have this return a JSON formatted string instead of home.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

@tolitius is right, but there's another issue which is that you're not telling it which view to use. If a `@RequestMapping` method returns a `String`, Spring expects that String to be the name of a view. You can annotate the method with `@ResponseBody` if you want the return value to *be* the response but you're then leaving it for Spring to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm still having the same mapping issues so afaik it's not even attempting to call my service.